# Automatically naming a big number of variables

Tags: python, tree

I am working with a big sized tree in python, I am parsing a file that has some data and with every new line, many nodes are to be created if some conditions are satisfied.

I am wondering what would be a good way to name the nodes created automatically.
I am using :

`from anytree import Node, RenderTree`

I have now in my nodes creation line of code:

`(i,k)=("(i,k)",parent=(i-1,j))`

where **i** is the depth of the tree, **j** is what node at that depth I am creating children for, and then I am creating the **Kth** child for that node.

I think working with dictionaries would work but I just want to first know if using the tuples is wrong.

Comment: That code can't work, it's an assignment to a function call?

Comment: @roganjosh yes I mentionned that i doubted it might take the syntax in some other ways, any suggestions?

Comment: Not liking the way something is written and it not being valid are two different things. You _could_ create a dictionary with that data as a tuple key but I'm not confident that this would be be the best approach

Comment: @roganjosh you're right, I modified the question and now it makes more sense, I am not sure about the dictionary approach either